# Subtract date variables PHP

Tags: php

Helllo, I have 2 time variables. One I take from the database and another is the current time.

```
$time_ended = $row['time_ended'];
$time_ended = new DateTime($time_ended);
$now = new DateTime();
```

What I want is to subtract $now from $time_ended and echo the number of seconds in a result.
Basically the output should be something like 121 or 134. I need this data to create a countdown timer.
Can someone show me the trick?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: use strtotime function which will convert the date string into timestamp.

Comment: Have you even tried to look it up in PHP manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP > 5.3: http://php.net/datetime.diff
>
> PHP < 5.3: http://php.net/strtotime

Use the `diff` method:

```
// PHP > 5.3
$diff = $time_ended->diff( $now );
echo $diff->format( '%s' ); // Seconds, with leading zeros
```

Or if you are not running PHP > 5.3:

```
// PHP < 5.3
$diff = ( strtotime( $now ) - strtotime( $time_ended ) ) / 3600;
echo date( 's', $diff ); // Seconds, with leading zeros
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Use the `diff` method of the DateTime object.

```
$interval = $time_ended->diff($now);
$diff_seconds = $interval->s; // returns the number of seconds
```

This will return a DateInterval (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object. The `s` property gets the number of seconds of the interval.